# How can I change my site's meta tags using fatcow.com site builder?

Tags: web-development, meta-tags

I am a newbie to website work.  I am on the board of a new non-profit, and have been given the task of getting the website up and running.  We elected a package from Fatcow.com that gives hosting and most services, cheap, but the only downside is the drag-and-drop style builder.  Of course without this builder, I would not have the page up already.  The downside to the builder is that it is hard, if not impossible, to edit the tags I need to in the actual code.  I have a copy of the Google Webmaster starter guide, and want to set meta-tags for each page on the site, however, I cannot find a function on fatcow to allow me access to read the code behind the pages.

Can anyone tell me how else to access the code for manual editing?

Answer (score 2):

How about [this page](http://www.fatcow.com/knowledgebase/beta/article.bml?ArticleID=1685&type=How%20To), Step 8.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

control panel>file manager>root>index.html